# Swig : best way to handle a simplified interface

Tags: python, c++, swig

We have a set of C++ classes that we expose to Python using Swig.
We are often adding new arguments to the methods.
On the other side, we have a set of Python scripts that we want to maintain as easily as possible. So, when we change the set of arguments of an exposed method in C++, we don't want to have to change all our python scripts that use this method. In that aim, we created, for each of our C++ class, a secondary interface class (C++ class too) which possesses a pointer toward an instance of the original class and exposes a simplified interface.

for instance, imagine we have a class A with a method foo :

```
 class A {
  public :
   void foo (int a, int b, double c, char * d, ....);
 };
```

And suppose we are happy with only the a, b and c arguments in python (passing default value to the others).

We create a APy class

```
class APy {
 public :
  void foo(int a,int b, double c) {
    A->foo(a,b,c,default,default,...);
  }
 protected :
  A * ref;
 };
```

The advantage is that it is possible to add new parameters to A::foo, change the parameters orders, the name of the method and more generally, for more complex changes, code an equivalence of the original method without any change in the existing Python scripts. Furthermore, if a script needs a new argument, it is possible to add it through a default argument in APy::foo without having to do do it in the original A::foo method.

The drawback is that it is delicate to deal with deletion as there are two objects. Should we delete A when APy is destroyed ? It depends. Sometimes A is an inner object of a larger object and should not be destroyed. But APy should be destroyed anytime it is no more used by the Python script.

I wonder if it would be possible to devise a more straightforward but as convenient architecture by mapping directly the original classes and methods but by asking swig to map and simplify the argument list itself.

Is it possible, in the .i file, to ask Swig to change the order of the arguments, set default values for non-exposed arguments (not .h default values) ?

For instance, if I have a function

```
 void foo(int a, double b, int c);
```

and I want to keep only a and c in the reverse order in the script language and set b to 10.0

So, when I would call :

```
 foo(3, 5)
```

it would actually be mapped to :

```
 foo(5,10.0,3)
```

Anyway, I would be interested to hear from your experience what you think is the best way to deal with such problems.

Comment: Is swig the right tool here? Swig automaticvally exposes any change you make. And that is something you are trying to prevent. For python extensions that you want to control the python API of you might like to look at PyCXX. You have to define the classes for your self, but you have complete control of the API and can hanlde backwards compatibility in a way that suits you.

Comment: If the relation between `A` and `APy` is one-to-one. i.e if `APy` exclusive has its own instance of `A` then as per [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) you can allocate and deallocate `A` in `APy`'s `c'tor` and `d'tor` respectively. For your requirement `APy` will act as `Proxy` of `A`.

Comment: I did not know PyCXX. Will take a look. Problem is that it would no more be possible to generate interface for other script language.  The RAII design would be fine but it is not always possible. For instance. Imagine a Network and Node classes whith a Network::getNode() method. The returned Node should not be deleted as Nodes are parts of the Networks objects (not of the NodePy interface object)

Comment: I don't understand: if changing the interface causes you problems why don't you just not changed it.

Comment: Similarly to how you can use `(*args, **kwargs)` in python and keep a dictionary inside a method with default values, say `opt`, and update it using  `opt.update(**kwargs)`, you could make a C++ function with key-value arguments and simply expose this through SWIG.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve your problem nicely with SWIG by playing tricks with its `%ignore`, `%rename` and `%extend` directives. Please look them up in the [SWIG docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html) for details. But for your above example, you could use the following interface file:

```
%module example

%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
%}

%ignore A::foo(int a, double b, int c);

%inline %{
  class A {
  public :
    double foo(int a, double b, int c) {
      return a * b - c;
    }
  };
%}

%extend A {
  double foo(int c, int a) {
    return $self->foo(a, 10.0, c);
  }
};
```

(Note that instead of `%inline %{ ... %}` you can of course also use `%{ #include "example.h" %}` and `%include "example.h"`, if you have your functions declared in a header file.)

Using this approach, you need to update the SWIG interface file whenever you change the C++ code, but you should be able to customize the API that gets exposed to Python.

There is another trick you should know, namely, you can instruct `%ignore` to match much more, e.g. all methods, or all versions of `A::foo`. But then you need to "unignore" them first before you can use `%extend`. So here is a slightly more involved / advanced example that shows this (standard SWIG) trick:

```
%module example

%{
  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
%}

%ignore A::foo;

%inline %{
  class A {
  public :
    double foo(int a, double b, int c) {
      return a * b - c;
    }
    double foo(int a, double b) {
      return a * b;
    }
};
%}

%rename("%s") A::foo;

%extend A {
  int foo(int c, int a) {
    return $self->foo(a, 10.0, c);
  }
};
```

Again, have a look at the SWIG docs for the exact details.